# How can I generate a list of delivered-to addresses in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I really want to turn off the catch-all option in my Google Apps email service. Before I do that however, I would like to get an idea about the usernames that are actually received mail on a semi-regular basis. That way I can decide which ones I would like to keep (by making an alias) or lose (by just letting it bounce).

Is there a way to extract this information from a Gmail account, preferably without having to copy a significant chunk of my inbox over IMAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has a dedicated site, called [Data Liberation](http://www.dataliberation.org), from where you can get all the information you need on how to extract the data from their services.

The only way that you can solve your problem is to get somehow the data on your local machine, because there is nothing you can do through the UI that they are offering. For gmail that way is by using [IMAP or POP](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail).

Comment: Your answer made me look at IMAP again with keener interest, and eventually lead to a rather workable solution. For this reason I'm awarding the bounty to you. The solution I ended up using is below.

Comment: @Ranieri thank you :) I think it's the right way to do it..

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Advanced Search options](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) and search for all mail that does not have your primary email address in the `to` or `cc` fields. (You can't filter on `bcc` unfortunately.)

That way you will get a list of emails within Gmail that you were either:

- bcc
- delivered via the catch all rule
- delivered via an alias

Depending on the number of emails received this may help you.

Use the following search term:

`!to:me !cc:me !from:me`

Comment: this is really great!! Thanx @Barry

Comment: That seems to bring up a lot of mass-mailings. Any tips on how to counteract that?

Comment: @Ranieri: Unfortunately not. Mass mailings will usually use the `bcc` field which you are unable to filter on. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing.

The suggestion to use the IMAP service is absolutely correct. The trick is not to pull in all your mail, but use the features of IMAP to retrieve only the information you are interested in. In our case, that is the "Delivered-to:" header.
The entire process only takes a few minutes on a full gmail account.

```
import imaplib

# Login to IMAP and get ALL message IDs.
mail  = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login('xxxxxx','yyyyyy')
mail.select("[Gmail]/All Mail")
result,data = mail.search(None,"ALL")
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()

# Retrieve the delivered-to headers in chunks of 100 and output them
while len(id_list)>0:
    nowlist = id_list[:100]
    id_list = id_list[100:]
    result, data = mail.fetch(",".join(nowlist),'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (DELIVERED-TO)])')
    for dt in data:
        if len(dt) == 2: # We actually have such a header
            if ":" in dt[1]: # And it's not empty
                print dt[1].split(":")[1].strip() # print the address
```

Comment: your script will unfortunately stop at the first delivered-to field it encounters. Do you know how to fetch the other ones? Without answer here, I will probably have a mail client download all the mails and then grep its files for delivered-to lines. Anyway, after executing the script, it is useful to run `sort delivered.txt | uniq -c | sort -n >> delivered_sorted.txt` to have all the entries sorted and counted. Of course, one can do it in the python script above but this is something I don't master (even if it does't seem complicated).

Comment: Yes, I did the same sort-and-count operation on the output too. It did not even occur to me that there might be more than one delivered-to header. I think all the information you need is contained in the results, but I can't check at the moment. I would recommend inspecting the "dt" variable for messages with multiple delivered-to: headers.

Comment: Your last line should be replaced by the following to see all the delivered-to: for r in findall("Delivered-To: {}\r\n", dt[1]): print ''.join(r)